# How to let Stata's syntax command ignore non-existent variables in varlist?

Tags: stata

Suppose in Stata I wish to define a program:

```
capture program drop myprg
program define myprg
  syntax varlist

  foreach var of varlist `varlist' {
     disp "`var'"
  }
end
```

I want my program to be able to accept both names of variables that exist in my dataset and names of non-existent variables. If the variable exists, it displays the name. Otherwise, it does nothing.

Suppose my dataset has two variables: `age1` and `age2`. The current output is:

```
. myprg age1
age1

. myprg age*
age1
age2

. myprg varThatDoesntExist
variable varThatDoesntExist not found
r(111);
```

Instead, the desired output for the last command is:

```
. myprg varThatDoesntExist

.
```

How can I get this functionality?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the `help` for `syntax`. The specification `namelist` generalises `varlist` to print out any name, existing and legal variable name or not.

```
program myprg
  syntax namelist 

  foreach var of local namelist {
     disp "`var'"
  }
end
```

A variant requested after first posting of this question was to print actual variable names and to ignore anything else. For that you need to set up your own parsing. Again, see the `help` for `syntax`. You need something like

```
program myprg
    version 8.2 
    syntax anything 

    local varlist 
    foreach thing of local anything {
        capture unab Thing : `thing'  
        if _rc == 0 local varlist `varlist' `Thing'  
    }

    foreach v of local varlist { 
        di `"`v'"'  
    } 
end
```

Comment: Thanks! One detail - if I have variables in my dataset `var1` and `var2`, then I can pass `var*` to `syntax varlist` successfully, whereas `syntax namelist` reports: `* invalid name`. Any idea how to address that?

Comment: More than a detail! I'll extend the answer.